# When updating and saving a related entity in different transactions, the server stops working

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, transactions, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

*My question is long, since at the beginning I wrote a full listing of what I was testing, so please either finish reading or go to the end to the question itself.*

I create table in PostgreSQL db:

```
create table if not exists users
(
    id bigserial not null
        constraint users_pkey
            primary key,
    name varchar(50),
    is_active boolean not null,
    old_user bigint
        constraint users_users_id_fk
            references users
);

alter table users owner to postgres;

create unique index if not exists users_id_uindex on users (id);

create unique index if not exists users_is_active_idx
    on users (is_active) where (is_active = true);
```

There can be **only one active user**.

I create Spring boot app. Below is a description of the structure (very simple) and under it the question itself.

1) Entity:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    public User(String name, Boolean isActive, User oldUser) {
        this.name = name;
        this.isActive = isActive;
        this.oldUser = oldUser;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "is_active")
    private Boolean isActive;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "old_user")
    private User oldUser;
}
```

2) Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

3) Service:

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public User getOne(Long id) {
        return userRepository.getOne(id);
    }

    @Override
    public User save(User user) {
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public User saveAndFlush(User user) {
        return userRepository.saveAndFlush(user);
    }
}
```

I insert one active user: `INSERT INTO "public"."users" ("id", "name", "is_active", "old_user") VALUES (DEFAULT, 'FirstUser', true, NULL)`

And now I want insert second user(active) but from app:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class TestBean implements CommandLineRunner {

    private final UserService userService;

    public TestBean(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        log.info("Start...");

        User first = userService.getOne(1L);
        User secondUser = new User("SecondUser", true, first);
        userService.saveAndFlush(secondUser);
    }
}
```

If I run server I get exception: o`rg.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_is_active_idx"`

To fix this, I must first deactivate the old user and then activate the new. But it just won't work that way, so before I activate a new user, I have to flush it to context:

```
    User first = userService.getOne(1L);
    first.setIsActive(false);
    userService.saveAndFlush(first);
    User secondUser = new User("SecondUser", true, first);
    userService.saveAndFlush(secondUser);
```

And this solution work fine. But now I add new method to service:

```
@Override
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public User saveInRequiredNew(User user) {
    return userRepository.saveAndFlush(user);
}
```

And try save user with this method:

```
    User first = userService.getOne(1L);
    first.setIsActive(false);
    userService.saveAndFlush(first);
    User secondUser = new User("SecondUser", true, first);
    User user = userService.saveInRequiredNew(secondUser);
    log.info(String.valueOf(user.getId()));
```

In this case when I call `saveInRequiredNew` method my app no throws exceptions and no result. it just stops working. In a real application, my logic is built so I must save the object in the transaction with `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW`.

**My question** - is why is this happening and what will be the solution? It is possible to update both entities (old and new users in one transaction(`Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW`). I don’t know if this is correct)

Comment: What do you mean by "stops working"?

Comment: @Simon Martinelli just stops accepting requests, does not display errors, does not display answers, does not exit debbag. as if in working condition but not reacting to anything

Comment: And you are sure that you don't have any active breakpoint? What if you start it without debug?

Comment: yes if I press F9 and I have breckpoint on next line I not enter to this line

Comment: and the thread is still running?

Comment: it looks like the main thread works